# C# Library works on .NET Core 3.1 but not on UWP

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

Background info:

I am using a DAQ from US Digital (The USB4 Encoder DAQ). The DAQ is connected to my computer via USB. It comes with a library to access and control the DAQ. The library is written in C++ but has a provided C# library wrapper and a bunch of demo programs.

The C# Wrapper is built using .NET Framework, there I created a .NET Core 3.1 project and built the wrapper again in there. on the test console application (that is on .NET Core 3.1), the wrapper class works great and I am able to write commands and retrieve data from the DAQ.

The Problem:

When I try to do the same thing as my console program inside my UWP application, I get nothing. I don't get any errors whatsoever, just none of the functions work. I am running a UWP app built for target version 1903. What could possibly be the issue between my console application and my UWP that is making this not work? Is there things I can do to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if there is anything I can help clarify about the problem.

```
using System;
using USB4Wrapper;

namespace TestDAQ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declare USB4 variable.
            USB4 mUSB4;

            // Create new USB4 object and assign it to mUSB4 variable.
            mUSB4 = new USB4();

            // Connects to all USB4 devices found on USB bus.
            // If a device is found, then Initialize will return true
            // and mUSB4.DeviceNo will default to 0. To talk to a second
            // device, set the mUSB4.DeviceNo = 1;
            if (mUSB4.Initialize())
            {
                // Output the number of USB4 devices found.
                Console.WriteLine("Found {0} USB4 device(s).", mUSB4.DeviceCount().ToString());

                mUSB4.WriteOutputPortRegister(0b00000101);


                uint[] arCount = new uint[4];
                uint timeStamp = 0;
                if (mUSB4.CaptureTimeAndCounts(arCount, out timeStamp))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Encoder 0 = {0}\nEncoder 1 = {1}\nEncoder 2 = {2}\nEncoder 3 = {3}\nTimeStamp = {4}",
                                      arCount[0].ToString(), arCount[1].ToString(), arCount[2].ToString(), arCount[3].ToString(), timeStamp.ToString());
                }

                // Close connection to USB4 devices.
                mUSB4.Shutdown();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to initialize USB4. No device found.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
After testing, it also works on WPF apps running on .NET Core 3.1 as well, it seems to be just UWP it does not work on

**UPDATE 2**
Here is what is inside the wrapper class. After debugging it on UWP, the `m_sLastResult` returns -32 and compares it to `SUCCESS` which is 0, therefore returning false

```
        [DllImport("USB4.dll")]
        private static extern short USB4_Initialize(out short sDeviceCount);
        /// <summary>
        /// This function is used to open a connection with all installed and detected USB4 encoder
        /// interface devices. This function returns the number of devices detected in the in/out parameter
        /// piDeviceCount. This function must be called before any other function. Almost all other
        /// function calls require a device number. If there are two boards detected, then the first
        /// board will be device number 0 and the second device number 1. 
        /// During initialization, a device’s module address is read and compared to previously read module
        /// addresses. If the module address already exists, then the newly read device’s module address
        /// is assigned the next available module address. 
        /// If the USB4’s FPGA code is not running, then it is downloaded and executed and the previously
        /// saved encoder control parameters are restored.
        /// After USB4_Initialize is called, DLL functions can be used to change the configuration if needed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns true if successful, other false.</returns>
        public bool Initialize()
        {
            lock (mThisLock)
            {
                short count = 0;
                m_sLastResult = USB4_Initialize(out count);
                m_sDeviceCount = count;
            }
            return (m_sLastResult == SUCCESS);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> C# Library works on .NET Core 3.1 but not on UWP

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), *The following table lists the minimum platform versions that support each .NET Standard version. That means that later versions of a listed platform also support the corresponding .NET Standard version. For example, .NET Core 2.2 supports .NET Standard 2.0 and earlier*.

Currently UWP does not support .Net Core 3.0, it is TBD state, please pay attention to the following update.

Comment: When might this next update be coming out? Also what can I do in the meantime? If I lower my UWP app to the Creators update (10.0.16299) and compile my library for .NET Core 2.0? Will that work?

Comment: I have tried creating a 10.0.16299 compiled library and a .NET Standard 2.0 library. Both again, work without a problem on my console application but do nothing on UWP. What else could it be?

Comment: Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: No, there is no errors whatsoever that I can find. I will update the post and show what is in the C# wrapper class, but I debugged it and it returns -32 and not 0, which is what SUCCESS is

Comment: Please check USB4.dll lib does not contain unsupported api for uwp platform.